# Error generated when quoting the class that a Django ForeignKey points to

Tags: django, foreign-keys

```
'MODEL' has a relation with model MODEL.IN.APP, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

This error arises when I move from an explicit reference to another model in another app:

```
foo = models.ForeignKey(project.app.models.OtherModel)
```

to a quoted version of the same (to remove circular references)

```
foo = models.ForeignKey("project.app.models.OtherModel")
```

This has stung me three times now, and I've googled the same question asked elsewhere (without the correct answer).

Comment: I have solved this, so I'm posting this with my own answer because I want future searchers to find the answer quickly. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to for why I'm doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's ForeignKey takes either the Model object itself or a Django-specific string representation of the model. The string is the app-name and the model name, so the correct form is:

```
foo = models.ForeignKey("app.OtherModels")
```

not

```
foo = models.ForeignKey("project.app.models.OtherModels")
```

Using the fully qualified name in quotes gives the rather odd error message in the original question.